# Matlab - how to retrieve the exact parameter list of the function call as a string inside the function?

Tags: matlab, parameters

Assume I have the function:

```
function name_the_paramlist(varargin)
    % Print out varargin exactly how it is called as a string
```

Basically what I want it to do is, calling:

```
name_the_paramlist({'x', x}, y, 1, 'hello', [1, 2; 3, 4])
```

should print to the screen the string:

```
'{''x'', x}, y, 1, ''hello'', [1, 2; 3, 4]}'
```

Any suggestion?

ETA: The reason I want something like this is to hopefully resolve this question:
[Matlab - how to create a subclass of dataset class keeping the dataset parameter constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810809/matlab-how-to-create-a-subclass-of-dataset-class-keeping-the-dataset-parameter)

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Once you pass a variable like `x` or `y` to a function, it does not know about the variable name, only values. `varargin` is a cell array of input arguments, not a string. I'm curious what do you need it for?

Comment: I didn't see this comment earlier but I answered it below your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you type this function call in a command line or run with F9 (so it get saved in the history) you can read the `history.m` file and get the last command as a string.

```
fid = fopen(fullfile(prefdir,'history.m'),'rt');
while ~feof(fid)
    lastcmd = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```

Then get the argument part:

```
arg_str = regexp(lastcmd, '\w+\((.+)\)','tokens','once');
arg_str = strrep(arg_str{:},'''','''''');
```

**UPDATE**:

Another idea. If you call this function from another script or function (m-file) you can use [DBSTACK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dbstack.html) to return the m-file name and the current line number:

```
SI = dbstack;
filename = SI(end).file;
lineNo = SI(end).line;
```

Then you can follow similar technique as in the first solution to read that line from the m-file and get argument part.

In opposite to the first solution this won't work if run from command line or editor cell mode.

Comment: This is good to know. Though I need this to work in all cases, i.e. when the function is called from another function or script for example.

Comment: Thanks Yuk. Is there a way to distinguish between the 2 situations inside the code? Also, just to clarify why I want smth kind of strange like this: It's because it may be a way to resolve my question over here where no one had an answer yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810809/matlab-how-to-create-a-subclass-of-dataset-class-keeping-the-dataset-parameter. Please let me know if you have a direct answer to that question.

Comment: You can check if `SI.file` have entries other then function called `dbstack`. Anyway I think it's a weird way to solve your problem. Will have a look at the previous question, but I don't have much experience with oop. Consider giving a bounty, that really attracts many people.

Comment: The other problem does not have much to do with OOP actually. Dataset() is a class, so in that way it's OOP. But the issue lies with preserving the workspace variables names when things are passed down.

Comment: How about if you pass existing dataset variable to subclass constructor as an argument? It can be made optional. Sorry, if I don't understand the problem yet.

Comment: So mydataset() is a subclass of dataset(). A subclass usually usually uses methods already given by the class, and then modify / add to it. In this case, I want mydataset() to firstly do what dataset() does, and then I do my modifications later. Does that make sense?